# How to pass the data value from any type into a GRPC Protobuf struct in Golang?

Tags: go, blockchain, grpc, protoc, ton

I'm trying to parse the data from the ADNL lib by [tonutils-go](https://github.com/xssnick/tonutils-go) and deliver the data by GRPC.

The data I need is structured as

```golang
// struct from tonutils-go
type Transaction struct {
    _           Magic         `tlb:"$0111"`
    AccountAddr []byte        `tlb:"bits 256"`
    LT          uint64        `tlb:"## 64"`
    PrevTxHash  []byte        `tlb:"bits 256"`
    PrevTxLT    uint64        `tlb:"## 64"`
    Now         uint32        `tlb:"## 32"`
    OutMsgCount uint16        `tlb:"## 15"`
    OrigStatus  AccountStatus `tlb:"."`
    EndStatus   AccountStatus `tlb:"."`
    IO          struct {
        In  *Message      `tlb:"maybe ^"`
        Out *MessagesList `tlb:"maybe ^"`
    } `tlb:"^"`
    TotalFees   CurrencyCollection     `tlb:"."`
    StateUpdate HashUpdate             `tlb:"^"` // of Account
    Description TransactionDescription `tlb:"^"`

    // not in scheme, but will be filled based on request data for flexibility
    Hash []byte `tlb:"-"`
}

type TransactionDescription struct {
    Description any `tlb:"."`
}


type TransactionDescriptionOrdinary struct {
    _            Magic         `tlb:"$0000"`
    CreditFirst  bool          `tlb:"bool"`
    StoragePhase *StoragePhase `tlb:"maybe ."`
    CreditPhase  *CreditPhase  `tlb:"maybe ."`
    ComputePhase ComputePhase  `tlb:"."`
    ActionPhase  *ActionPhase  `tlb:"maybe ^"`
    Aborted      bool          `tlb:"bool"`
    BouncePhase  *BouncePhase  `tlb:"maybe ."`
    Destroyed    bool          `tlb:"bool"`
}

type ComputePhase struct {
    Phase any `tlb:"."`
}


type ComputePhaseVM struct {
    _                Magic `tlb:"$1"`
    Success          bool  `tlb:"bool"`
    MsgStateUsed     bool  `tlb:"bool"`
    AccountActivated bool  `tlb:"bool"`
    GasFees          Coins `tlb:"."`
    Details          struct {
        GasUsed          *big.Int `tlb:"var uint 7"`
        GasLimit         *big.Int `tlb:"var uint 7"`
        GasCredit        *big.Int `tlb:"maybe var uint 3"`
        Mode             int8     `tlb:"## 8"`
        ExitCode         int32    `tlb:"## 32"`
        ExitArg          *int32   `tlb:"maybe ## 32"`
        VMSteps          uint32   `tlb:"## 32"`
        VMInitStateHash  []byte   `tlb:"bits 256"`
        VMFinalStateHash []byte   `tlb:"bits 256"`
    } `tlb:"^"`
}
```

The protobuf of TxTest:

```
message TxTest {
   int32 exitCode = 1;
}
```

The data I want to parse is ExitCode and the code as following:

```golang
    list, err := api.ListTransactions(context.Background(), addr, 1, uint64(txInfo.TxLT), data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("send err: %s", err.Error())
        return nil, err
    }
    for _, t := range list {
        a := t.Description.Description

        var result tlb.TransactionDescriptionOrdinary

        b, err := json.MarshalIndent(a, "", "  ")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("error:", err)
        }
        json.Unmarshal([]byte(string(b)), &result)

        var computePhase tlb.ComputePhaseVM

        c, err := json.MarshalIndent(result.ComputePhase.Phase, "", "  ")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("error:", err)
        }

        json.Unmarshal([]byte(string(c)), &computePhase)


        detail := &pb.TxTest{
            ExitCode: computePhase.Details.ExitCode,
        }
        detail2 := struct {
            ExitCode int32 `json:"exit_code"`
        }{
            ExitCode: computePhase.Details.ExitCode,
        }

        fmt.Printf("detail: %+v\n", detail)
        fmt.Printf("detail2: %+v\n", detail2)

    }
```

The data struct of one transaction is:

```
{
  "AccountAddr": "HYmM1/kK6GB2DLV3zVkIRyEpKoHRTF/jG8K7tTG91sQ=",
  "LT": 11898016000001,
  "PrevTxHash": "iKGjsxdT0gzIJXGNIlvxy0+a1gGEQDED4f7ZAJ9dlmc=",
  "PrevTxLT": 11897712000001,
  "Now": 1685602760,
  "OutMsgCount": 1,
  "OrigStatus": "ACTIVE",
  "EndStatus": "ACTIVE",
  "IO": {
    "In": {
      "MsgType": "EXTERNAL_IN",
      "Msg": {
        "SrcAddr": "NONE",
        "DstAddr": "EQAdiYzX-QroYHYMtXfNWQhHISkqgdFMX-Mbwru1Mb3WxN5D",
        "ImportFee": "0",
        "StateInit": null,
        "Body": {}
      }
    },
    "Out": {
      "List": {}
    }
  },
  "TotalFees": {
    "Coins": "22324812",
    "ExtraCurrencies": {}
  },
  "StateUpdate": {
    "OldHash": "WUkeXyOS8hsWyQYRLHPmJHpfMUSID8oDTAq6fY20pyQ=",
    "NewHash": "e8tn4cP4lAkFwvDcGc/VqBZ7lZeB4mhjMbRFE8rpsQA="
  },
  "Description": {
    "Description": {
      "CreditFirst": true,
      "StoragePhase": {
        "StorageFeesCollected": "484",
        "StorageFeesDue": null,
        "StatusChange": {
          "Type": "UNCHANGED"
        }
      },
      "CreditPhase": null,
      "ComputePhase": {
        "Phase": {
          "Success": true,
          "MsgStateUsed": false,
          "AccountActivated": false,
          "GasFees": "19862000",
          "Details": {
            "GasUsed": 19862,
            "GasLimit": 0,
            "GasCredit": 10000,
            "Mode": 0,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "ExitArg": null,
            "VMSteps": 404,
            "VMInitStateHash": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=",
            "VMFinalStateHash": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="
          }
        }
      },
      "ActionPhase": {
        "Success": true,
        "Valid": true,
        "NoFunds": false,
        "StatusChange": {
          "Type": "UNCHANGED"
        },
        "TotalFwdFees": "1000000",
        "TotalActionFees": "333328",
        "ResultCode": 0,
        "ResultArg": null,
        "TotalActions": 1,
        "SpecActions": 0,
        "SkippedActions": 0,
        "MessagesCreated": 1,
        "ActionListHash": "Fkoo2xX9jU4YxTGJlrUjvaYrRWTrYHEBkUywUYg9AV4=",
        "TotalMsgSize": {
          "Cells": 1,
          "Bits": 697
        }
      },
      "Aborted": false,
      "BouncePhase": null,
      "Destroyed": false
    }
  },
  "Hash": "VMXfRKfIEtmAiHm3brTvhSkAidE1CkgRW8RQBVarJtQ="
}
```

and output of `detail` and `detail2` are:

```
detail: 
detail2: {ExitCode:0}
```

My question is why the struct generated by `protoc` couldn't parse the `exitCode` from the `transaction` but the struct I defined could work well?

How can I inject the data into the struct `TxTest` which is generated by `protoc`, and let me transmit the data by `GRPC`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with an exit code value other than 0 and I'm guessing you'll get a different result.

Have a look at your generated code. I believe what's happening is that [`fmt.Printf`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt) is calling the generated `String()` method for your proto struct, which uses the `prototext` package to print the contents of your message rather than the default Go struct printer.

This is [expected behavior](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/368#issuecomment-306670603) for for `proto3`; there's no distinction between an `int32` value of `0` and an empty field.